# maven build ear - how I can build just a .ear file and not the exploded ear dir?

Tags: maven, build, ear

I just need a myEar.ear file as output of my maven build.

I don't want the dir myEar (the exploded ear version).

To be clear, this is my build output:

```
20/02/2017  11:37    <DIR>          myEar
20/02/2017  11:37         7.985.535 myEar.ear
```

I just want the myEar.ear.

Thanks.

Here my pom.xml of the ear:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>myEar</name>
  <description>myEar</description>

  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>myEar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <parent>
    </parent>

  <properties>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
```

(...)

```
</dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>


      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
            <generatedDescriptorLocation>${basedir}/src/main/application/META-INF</generatedDescriptorLocation>
            <modules>
                <webModule>
                    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myWeb</artifactId>                    
                    <contextRoot>/myWeb</contextRoot>
                </webModule>
                 <webModule>
                    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myWS</artifactId>                     
                    <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                </webModule>
            </modules>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

       <directory>${basedir}/../target/diraliases/EARHOMEDIR1036</directory>
       <finalName>myEar</finalName>

   </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why have you configured the `<directory>${basedir}/..` ? outside the current module? Have you checked what's inside the `myEAR` folder?

Comment: it's a long story... I need the ear on that directory to be complaint with the  change management of my company. Anyway .ear and folder have the same content.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with th maven-antrun-plugin... an ant call inside maven... very dirty... someone has a better idea?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deleteDir</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <delete dir="${basedir}/../target/diraliases/EARHOMEDIR1036/myEar"/> 
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```